# Angular: detect click on current page link

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

Is there any way to use Angular build in router properties, such as `RouterLinkActive` to detect click on the link to current page?
In the footer I want to add function to scroll to top if clicked on the current page link.

I have this:

```
<a *ngIf="!sublinkItem.outerLink" [title]="sublinkItem.altText"
  [routerLink]="[sublinkItem.link]" routerLinkActive="active" 
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"                                     
  class="dropdown-item outer-link" 
  [innerHTML]="sublinkItem.text">
</a>
```

And I have function in the component:

```
scrollToTop(): void {...}
```

I want to fire this function only, if routerLinkActive is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instance reference of the `RouterLinkActive` directive in your HTML template. Note - I removed some attributes for brevity:

```html
<a 
  [routerLink]="[sublinkItem.link]" 
  routerLinkActive="active"
  #routerLinkActiveRef="routerLinkActive"
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"                                     
  (click)="scrollToTop(routerLinkActiveRef.isActive)"
>
 {{ sublinkItem.text }}
</a>
```

And in your component code:

```
scrollToTop(shouldScroll: boolean): void {
  if (!shouldScroll) {
    return;
  }

  // scroll!
}
```